# How to get objects of related indirectly by NSPredicate?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have three model in `CoreData`:

- Category with categoryId
- Production with productionId
- SubProduction with subProductionId

SubProduction is related to One Production and every product has Many SubProduction

Production is related to One Category and every Category has Many Production

I want to get all SubProduction of a Category by categoryId.

I know this way: Load all productions of category and by a for loop get all SubProductions. I'm wondering if there is a better way to approach it by `NSPredicate`

How to make this `NSPredicate` format?

Something like this:

```
frc.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "production.category = %@", category)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW, I just test my imagine and

It's work:

```
frc.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "production.category = %@", category)
```

Thanks to `NSPredicate`